# IBus Korean not working

Tags: 16.04, ibus, korean

On Ubuntu 16.04.1, when I press hangul key to use korean, and press any character key, it still be input as alphabet, not hangul.
But the input source of my menu bar is changed.

How can I input hangul?

Comment: Did you enable "Hangul mode"?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you have done: `sudo apt-get install ibus-hangul`.

This will ensure that when you go to: settings - text entry - '+'; you will be able to add: korean (hangul) (ibus) using '+'. Make sure to use the (ibus) option.

Then, click the button that looks like a wrench and driver in a 'x' pattern. Pay attention to the toggle key. After you hit apply, you should then see the korean fan (red,yellow, blue fireball in circular pattern) in your icon bar. Or press En (default in US) then the fireball. Then you still have to toggle to text in korean.

Comment: It's ibus-hangul